# Calculate draggable div index

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code i try get index of draggable div. Code structure looks like:

```
<div class="noDragabble dragabbleMother">
   <div class="draggableItem"><p>(Place for index number)</p></div>
   <div class="draggableItem"><p>(Place for index number)</p></div>
   <div class="draggableItem"><p>(Place for index number)</p></div>
</div>
```

I try something like this in HTML:

```
<div class="noDragabble dragabbleMother">
   <div class="index1" onmouseup="checkIndex(this)"><p>(Place for index number)</p></div>
   <div class="index2" onmouseup="checkIndex(this)"><p>(Place for index number)</p></div>
   <div class="index3" onmouseup="checkIndex(this)"><p>(Place for index number)</p></div>
</div>
```

And use script:

```
function checkIndex(ele) {
 var id = ele.id;
 setTimeout(function () {
  var a = $(".dragabbleMother #" + id).index();
  $("#" + id + " p").text(a+1);
  }, 1000);
}
```

The code works because when I change the order of elements the index of the element I dragged changes. However, the index of other elements should also change. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: It's not easy to understand. Perhaps you can create a codepen (live demo).  Is this working? var id = ele.id;   I can't see any ids in the html.

Comment: "The code works because when I change the order of elements the index of the element I dragged changes. However, the index of other elements should also change." *HOW* should they change?  And why?  If you swap index3 and index4, why change index2 and index6?